Homebrew - clang - verification on CLI installation
Yesterday i was completly reinstalling my MacBook from built in recovery, after standard configuration, app installation (App Store and trusted sources) i was installing homebrew from official site (brew.sh) with cli installer, but during this veryfing window for clang appears and it was clearly visible only in slow motion video.  I've done this multiple times and never saw anything was verified by gatekeeper during homebrew usage or installation in last 3 years (or there is a chance i didn't pay attention to it earlier)
which clang
shows
/usr/bin/clang
I am using GIT from Apple, installed with git command in terminal after account configuration, OS - latest Sonoma, Mac with Apple ARM chip (clean system -> git installed from git command in terminal -> homebrew installation from brew.sh) That was the first time i saw "veryfing clang" window during installation
all apps outside AppStore were verified with checksums (where it was available), urls checked agains phishing, domain certificated checked and app verified by Gateekeper - i got Gatekeeper's window about apps were checked by Apple and malware was not detected
So the question is, during homebrew installation with cli (package manager installation - not packages) is it normal for this window with clang verification to appear?
Edit:
I found out that this verification window is triggered by command
xcrun clang which exists in install.sh script from homebrew installer, i also tried running it manually on clean OS without installing homebrew (reinstalled clean os, no apps, only git from Apple command line tools installed)

If you have an answer, please put that below in the answer section. We appreciate greatly when people solve and document that a question has a fix. Everything you document seems legit and proper to me
